# How to write unit test for modal visibility?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

i have an `CarCard`component where i list the car information. If you hover and click View More, a modal shows up and displays more detail. I want to write a unit test whether modal is opened when I click this button. How can I write?

CarCard Component:

```
const CarCard: React.FC<CarCardProps> = ({ car }) => {
  const { city_mpg, year, make, model, transmission, drive } = car;

  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

  const carRent = calculateCarRent(city_mpg, year);

  return (
    <div className="car-card group">
      <div className="car-card__content">
        <h2 className="car-card__content-title">
          {make} {model}
        </h2>
      </div>

      <p className="flex mt-6 text-[32px] font-extrabold">
        <span className="self-start text-[14px] font-semibold">$</span>
        {carRent}
        <span className="self-end text-[14px] font-medium">/day</span>
      </p>

      <div className="relative w-full h-40 my-3 object-contain">
        <Image
          src={generateCarImageUrl(car)}
          alt="car model"
          fill
          priority
          className="object-contain"
        />
      </div>

      <div className="relative flex w-full mt-2">
        <div className="flex group-hover:invisible w-full justify-between text-gray">
          <div className="flex flex-col justify-center items-center gap-2">
            <Image
              src="/steering-wheel.svg"
              width={20}
              height={20}
              alt="steering wheel"
            />
            <p className="text-[14px]">
              {transmission === "a" ? "Automatic" : "Manual"}
            </p>
          </div>
          <div className="flex flex-col justify-center items-center gap-2">
            <Image src="/tire.svg" width={20} height={20} alt="tire" />
            <p className="text-[14px]">{drive.toUpperCase()}</p>
          </div>
          <div className="flex flex-col justify-center items-center gap-2">
            <Image
              src="/gas.svg"
              width={20}
              height={20}
              alt="gas"
              className="w-auto h-auto"
            />
            <p className="text-[14px]">{city_mpg} MPG</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="car-card__btn-container">
          <CustomButton
            title="View More"
            containerStyles="w-full py-[16px] rounded-full bg-primary-blue"
            textStyles="text-white text-[14px] font-bold"
            rightIcon="/right-arrow.svg"
            handleClick={() => setIsOpen(true)}
          />
        </div>
      </div>

      <CarDetails
        isOpen={isOpen}
        closeModal={() => setIsOpen(false)}
        car={car}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default CarCard;
```

Modal (CarDetails) :

```
const CarDetails: React.FC<CarDetailsProps> = ({ isOpen, closeModal, car }) => (
  <>
    <Transition appear show={isOpen} as={Fragment} data-testid="modal">
      <Dialog as="div" className="relative z-10" onClose={closeModal}>
        <Transition.Child
          as={Fragment}
          enter="ease-out duration-300"
          enterFrom="opacity-0"
          enterTo="opacity-100"
          leave="ease-in duration-200"
          leaveFrom="opacity-100"
          leaveTo="opacity-0"
        >
          <div className="fixed inset-0 bg-black bg-opacity-25" />
        </Transition.Child>

        <div className="fixed inset-0 overflow-y-auto">
          <div className="flex min-h-full items-center justify-center p-4 text-center">
            <Transition.Child
              as={Fragment}
              enter="ease-out duration-300"
              enterFrom="opacity-0 scale-95"
              enterTo="opacity-100 scale-100"
              leave="ease-out duration-300"
              leaveFrom="opacity-100 scale-100"
              leaveTo="opacity-0 scale-95"
            >
              <Dialog.Panel className="relative w-full max-w-lg max-h-[90vh] overflow-y-auto transform rounded-2xl bg-white p-6 text-left shadow-xl transition-all flex flex-col gap-5">
                <button
                  type="button"
                  className="absolute top-2 right-2 z-10 w-fit p-2 bg-primary-blue-100 rounded-full"
                  onClick={closeModal}
                >
                  <Image
                    src="/close.svg"
                    alt="close"
                    width={20}
                    height={20}
                    className="object-contain"
                  />
                </button>

                <div className="flex-1 flex flex-col gap-3">
                  <div className="relative w-full h-40 bg-pattern bg-cover bg-center rounded-lg">
                    <Image
                      src={generateCarImageUrl(car)}
                      alt="car model"
                      fill
                      priority
                      className="object-contain"
                    />
                  </div>

                  <div className="flex gap-3">
                    <div className="flex-1 relative w-full h-24 bg-primary-blue-100 rounded-lg">
                      <Image
                        src={generateCarImageUrl(car, "29")}
                        alt="car model"
                        fill
                        priority
                        className="object-contain"
                      />
                    </div>
                    <div className="flex-1 relative w-full h-24 bg-primary-blue-100 rounded-lg">
                      <Image
                        src={generateCarImageUrl(car, "33")}
                        alt="car model"
                        fill
                        priority
                        className="object-contain"
                      />
                    </div>
                    <div className="flex-1 relative w-full h-24 bg-primary-blue-100 rounded-lg">
                      <Image
                        src={generateCarImageUrl(car, "13")}
                        alt="car model"
                        fill
                        priority
                        className="object-contain"
                      />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div className="flex-1 flex flex-col gap-2">
                  <h2 className="font-semibold text-xl capitalize">
                    {car.make} {car.model}
                  </h2>

                  <div className="mt-3 flex flex-wrap gap-4">
                    {Object.entries(car).map(([key, value]) => (
                      <div
                        className="flex justify-between gap-5 w-full text-right"
                        key={key}
                      >
                        <h4 className="text-grey capitalize">
                          {key.split("_").join(" ")}
                        </h4>
                        <p className="text-black-100 font-semibold">{value}</p>
                      </div>
                    ))}
                  </div>
                </div>
              </Dialog.Panel>
            </Transition.Child>
          </div>
        </div>
      </Dialog>
    </Transition>
  </>
);

export default CarDetails;
```

I tried this, but `modalElement`is null here. Also if i add `await`in front of `userEvent.click` it throws error: `Error: Uncaught [ReferenceError: ResizeObserver is not defined]`

Unit Test:

```
  it("opens car details modal when 'View More' button is clicked", () => {
    render(<CarCard car={mockCar} />);

    const viewMoreBtn = screen.getByText("View More");

    userEvent.click(viewMoreBtn);
    const modalElement = screen.queryByTestId("modal");

    expect(modalElement).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

`await`ing for `userEvent` is required starting from jest v14, so if your jest is v14 or newer then you did the right thing.

Since the error is about `ResizeOberserve not defined`, I am assuming that you are using some kind of library that initiated it. In this case we can possibly mock the `ResizeOberserve` to make jest slightly happier by

```
class ResizeObserver {
  observe() {}
  unobserve() {}
}
describe('testing here', () => {
  window.ResizeObserver = ResizeObserver;

  it("opens car details modal when 'View More' button is clicked", async () => {
    render(<CarCard car={mockCar} />);

    const viewMoreBtn = screen.getByText("View More");

    await userEvent.click(viewMoreBtn);
    const modalElement = screen.queryByTestId("modal");

    expect(modalElement).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
```

Just a speculation given the information provided. Hope it helps.